# PostGis importance with geodjango

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

So at first i tried to create a `model` using `model` from `django.contrib.gis.db` which threw an error regarding GDAL (there are many posts regarding that and how to solve that and i already did that).

After installing the required files for GDAL, i also added a postgres database to my django project.

As the model used by me is used in case if we are dealing with geoDjango (or simply location) but geoDjango can be used even without that.

What i mean is there is no connection b/w our database and geoDjango as we can simply apply the functions like `geodesic, geocoders` etc without any error(please correct me if i am wrong).

So after doing that, i ran the migrations and everything was fine.

Now my question is;

If everything ran without any error, then what is the use of PostGis in it.

Though i didn't used it yet but everybody is adding it to the project where geoDjango has to be used.

Why to add `django.contrib.gis` to installed apps and why to add `PostGis` extension to the postgresql database.

Comment: Postgis  is an extension for the postgresql database to support spatial queries  , django.contrib.gis  has functions for the django orm to do spatial queries via the django orm and add  model fields  for geometry columns  , for more information read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: Can you please provide some examples.

Comment: So can we say that PostGis simply adds more functionality to Django ORM to work with geoDjango and is optional??

Comment: Postgis as i wrote is a postgresql extension not a django package ,  django via django.contrib.gis  connects with the postgis extensions to make spatial queries and to add support for geometry colujmns  , read the  geodjango documentation  link provided to my comment